# Creating a wordlist to speed up pdfcrack

Tags: password, data-recovery, pdf

I had shared about `pdfcrack` earlier [here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/723087/pdfcrack-and-minimum-number-of-characters-in-password). Now it is boring and will take a long time for `pdfcrack` to crack the password.

But what if I could help it using a wordlist that might make the whole processor faster. But how do I go creating a wordlist. Say for e.g. I know the first four characters are letters, the remaining four characters are numbers. How would I go creating that and how do I provide that stack/wordlist to `pdfcrack`.

Answer (score 3):

A generic tool to generate a wordlist is `crunch`.

> Say for e.g. I know the first four characters are letters, the remaining four characters are numbers.

The following command will generate a wordlist according to the above description:

```
crunch 8 8 abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ -t @@@@%%%%
```

([This answer](https://superuser.com/a/1678748/432690) may help you understand how `@`, `%` and such work in `crunch`.)

You can save the result to a regular file by redirecting output to it; then use the file with the `-w` option of `pdfcrack`:

```
crunch … >wordlist
pdfcrack -w wordlist protected.pdf
```

`crunch` tells me the size of the file will be about 612 GB. If I were you, I would pipe one tool to the other. Unfortunately `pdfcrack -w` (at least in my Debian) does not follow the [convention of `-` meaning the stdin](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/16364/108618). Still I can do this:

```
crunch … | pdfcrack -w /dev/stdin protected.pdf
```

In case you cannot use [`/dev/stdin`](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/36404/108618), create a named fifo and use it instead of a regular file:

```
mkfifo myfifo
crunch … >myfifo &
pdfcrack -w myfifo protected.pdf
```

Answer (score 2):

You might actually want to use another program than `pdfcrack`. With a good GPU, [`hashcat`](https://hashcat.net/hashcat/) can try orders of magnitude more passwords per second (to give an idea, it can be millions of tries per second, or much faster if you have a powerful GPU).

You can directly ask it to crack a password having a specific pattern of characters. To do so, it requires an external script ([pdf2john.py](https://github.com/truongkma/ctf-tools/blob/master/John/run/pdf2john.py)) to extract the hash of the password from the PDF into a format `hashcat` can use.

As an example, you can use a command such as:

```
hashcat -a 3 -i -m 10500 'hash' ?l?l?l?l?d?d?d?d
```

In the command, `-a 3` specifies that the attack mode is a bruteforce, `-m 10500` is the type of hash (PDF), and the word at the end is the pattern, here being 4 letters and 4 digits. The `-i` specifies that the attack will start from 1 character, then 2, ... up to the length of the cracking pattern.

Answer (score -2):

At 45k a second, to computer 4.6 billion will take about 100,000 seconds. So it seems doable at 28 hours.

I’d just write a program to count from 0 to 9999, then wrap four loops from a to z around it. So you end up with a file:

```
aaaa0001 to zzzz9999
```